# Why can't I use $ character at start of Mongoose Schema key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to use a $ in a Mongoose Schema (data is formatted this way from another app), like this:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  $meta1: {
   type: String,
   trim: true,
  },
  $meta2: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  normalKey3: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  }
});
```

When I attempt this, and run the function (with PUT route):

```
exports.updateMe = async (req, res) => {
  const xyz = await MySchema.findOneAndUpdate({normalKey3: req.body.normalKey3}, req.body, 
  {
    upsert: true,
    new: true, 
    runValidators: true
  }).exec();
  res.status(200).json(xyz);
};
```

I get the error below. If I replace the $ with a _ (e.g. _meta1) it works. **Is this a Mongoose or Mongo issue? What does $ signify such that it doesn't work?**

Error:

```
Error: Invalid atomic update value for $meta1. Expected an object, received string
[]     at castUpdate (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/query/castUpdate.js:86:13)
[]     at model.Query._castUpdate (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3185:10)
[]     at castDoc (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3212:18)
[]     at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2441:19)
[]     at model.Query.Query._findOneAndUpdate (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2163:8)
[]     at process.nextTick (/Users/.../node_modules/kareem/index.js:315:33)
[]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ is reserved keywords in MongoDB
there are limits in MongoDB names

**Restrictions on Field Names
Field names cannot contain the null character.
Top-level field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.
Otherwise, starting in MongoDB 3.6, the server permits storage of field names that contain dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).**

you can find more information here
Visit  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/